# Find the first item in a list which gives a value, and return the value

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0, morelinq

How could the following iterative algorithm be rewritten using Linq?

```
int GetMatchingValue(List<Thing> things)
{
 foreach(Thing t in things)
 {
  var value = thing.ComplicatedCalculation();
  if(value > 0)
   return value;
 }
}
```

It's easy to find which `Thing` we want with LINQ:

```
var thing = things.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ComplicatedCalculation() > 0);
```

But then you have to do the check again to see which value to return:

```
return thing?.ComplicatedCalculation() ?? 0;
```

Is there a way to return the calculated value using LINQ without having to do it twice? Or is this a case where iterating the list is the simplest/cleanest solution? I would welcome a solution employing MoreLINQ also.

Comment: Since you no longer care about which thing produces the result, throw it away: `var value = things.Select(t => t.ComplicatedCalculation()).FirstOrDefault(v => v > 0);` Note that `FirstOrDefault<int>()` will return `default(int)` which is `0` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to first transform to the value you care about and find the one you want to return:

```
int GetMatchingValue(List<Thing> things)
    => things.Select(t => t.ComplicatedCalculation()).FirstOrDefault(v => v > 0);
```

Comment: but this will perform the complicated calculation on every item?

Comment: @Mr.Boy No, it won't. LINQ uses [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution) (I would recommend learning more about LINQ). The execution of `FirstOrDefault` will process the `Select` one item at a time, and stop when it's condition is matched, exactly like an early exit from a loop. The same thing occurs with most LINQ methods that return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a single object (e.g. note that `ToList()` returns a single object, a `List<T>`).